# Creating a variable with a function to RETURN, which could then be put inside a second variable

Tags: javascript, function, return, var

I'm learning JavaScript on Codecademy, and trying to create the variable which will RETURN a value, and then use that variable within another variable. Does anyone know why the following code is not accomplishing this? I'm receiving a "syntax error" message.

```
// Parameter is a number, and we do math with that parameter
var timesTwo = function(number) {
        return number * 2;
    };
// Call timesTwo here!
var newNumber = timesTwo(number) {
    console.log(newNumber);
}
newNumber(6)
```

/Users/Michael/Desktop/Screen Shot 2013-08-17 at 2.13.30 PM.png

Comment: Just use `var newNumber = function (num) { console.log(timesTwo(num)); };`: http://jsfiddle.net/aGjeK/

Answer (score 1):

This is how you define a function:

```
var func = function () {
    //do whatever
};
```

This is how you call one:

```
func();
```

Your code (copied below) throws an error, because it's not following the rules. This is how it should be:

```
//define one function
var timesTwo = function (number) {
    return number * 2;
};

//define another function
var newNumber = function (number) {
    //timesTwo is called inside
    console.log( timesTwo(number) );
};

//call newNumber which calls timesTwo itself
newNumber(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

As JOPLOmacedo said, you're mixing function declaration and invocation syntaxes. And when you say "variable", I'm not sure if you always mean "function" (only functions can return), or other types of variable too.

Maybe this is what you're trying to accomplish:

```
var newNumber = timesTwo(6);
console.log(newNumber); // logs 12
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the following? http://jsfiddle.net/LE5rY/

```
// Parameter is a number, and we do math with that parameter
var timesTwo = function(number) {
return number * 2;
};
// Call timesTwo here!
var newNumber = function(number) {
console.log(timesTwo(number));//edit here
};
newNumber(6);
```